# Should I use callbacks for events?

Tags: node.js, express, events, callback

While browsing some old documentation for express, I found this example that uses callbacks for the "close" event:

```
app.get('/page/', function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, { /* . . . */ );
    res.write('\n');
    req.on("close", function () {
        // do something when the connection is closed
    });
});
```

Is this considered good practice in ES10? Should I write code like this, or do I need to consider other methods for events?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is still standard practice. As you can see this example is taken from the [*4.x* (latest) Express.js docs](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.get)

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('GET request to homepage');
});
```

One thing you *can* do if you want, is to use [arrow function notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to define your callbacks. Like this

```
app.get('/page/', (req, res) => {
    res.writeHead(200, { /* . . . */ });
    res.write('\n');
    req.on("close", () => {
        // do something when the connection is closed
    });
});
```